# Are there any movies whose name changed after released in theaters?

Tags: title

With the exception of translations to other languages, **are there any movies whose name changed after released in theaters?**  Bonus if there's one that changed WHILE in theaters.

Comment: I'm sure there must be many - Star Wars - later Star Wars: A New Hope, springs to mind.  According to Wikipedia - that change is dated ~1981, a few years after the initial release.

Answer (score 2):

The new Ghostbusters did it. I would guess there are others. Ghostbusters became Ghostbusters Answer the Call

Comment: Was this after it was released in theaters though?  Not being argumentative, just curious.

Comment: Yes-it was in the news as well-I think on the home video release day.

Answer (score 1):

There have been several movies that have changed title in their release in  United States and and the UK , which share the same language. This might be stretching the definition of the question a little I know.

This sometimes happens when a film title might be confused with something else that is popular in the other country. For example the film ' Neighbors'was called 'Bad Neighbours' in the UK as the Australian soap 'Neighbours' is a very popular TV series here.
 It can also happen when a title is considered to obscure for instance the UK title 'Ice Cold In Alex' a popular 1950s war movie was called 'Desert Attack' in the US.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few:

- Star Wars became Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope
- Ghostbusters became Ghostbusters Answer the Call
- Edge of Tomorrow became Live Die Repeat for the home video release (though technically it still used Edge of Tomorrow)

Comment: "Live. Die. Repeat." was the *tagline* for Edge of Tomorrow, not an alternate title.  Granted that tagline was printed in big text on the poster/DVD case, often superseding the actual title, but it was never the title.

Comment: @Steve-O It was the tagline originally, but all of the home video marketing said Live Die Repeat, not Edge of Tomorrow, because it had a dismal run in theaters.